# Including some records in an SQL query increases query time fivefold on Heroku

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku-postgres, django-guardian

We use Django with [django-guardian](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for object-based permissions. Recently, we have been experiencing an extreme increase in runtime of a specific query for at least one user with a lot of `annotation_texthighlight` . Here is the query:

```sql
SELECT "annotation_texthighlight"."uuid",
      [omitted for readability]
FROM "annotation_texthighlight"
         INNER JOIN "annotation_annotation"
                    ON ("annotation_texthighlight"."annotation_id" = "annotation_annotation"."uuid")
WHERE (
          "annotation_texthighlight"."annotation_id" IN
          (SELECT U0."uuid"
           FROM "annotation_annotation" U0
           WHERE (U0."chapter_id" =
                  '9a481c82-c44b-4ead-94bb-48de0910877b'::uuid AND
                  U0."min_revision_id" IN
                  ('5a301886-e200-441f-ad8e-03c4eb9bd773'::uuid,
                   '6f539d6f-c9eb-41e2-956e-32b4a5950c33'::uuid))) AND
          "annotation_texthighlight"."uuid" IN
          (SELECT CAST(U0."object_pk" AS uuid) AS "obj_pk"
           FROM "guardian_userobjectpermission" U0
                    INNER JOIN "auth_permission" U2 ON (U0."permission_id" = U2."id")
           WHERE (U0."user_id" = 1522 AND U2."content_type_id" = 89 AND
                  U2."codename" IN ('view_texthighlight')))
     );
```

This puzzles me quite a bit. Here are the results of my investigation so far:

- Copying the database from its original Heroku (Postgres 13.4, standard-2, 4GB RAM, 1.2 GB DB size) to local (stock Postgres 13 via [standard Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres)) will cut the runtime ~250ms.
- In total, about 1200 records will be returned. The first 700 (`LIMIT 700`) will take ~5 seconds. The remaining (`OFFSET 700 LIMIT 700`) will take ~25 seconds.
- Removing either of the `WHERE` filters will reduce runtime <1s.

My best guess would be a different configuration on Heroku as compared to the default Postgres Docker image.

I EXPLAIN ANALYSE both queries:

Postgres locally via Docker

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Nested Loop  (cost=143.39..316.69 rows=1 width=179) (actual time=33.930..98.371 rows=1561 loops=1)                                                                                                                                             |
|  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=142.97..316.17 rows=1 width=70) (actual time=33.926..96.589 rows=1561 loops=1)                                                                                                                                        |
|        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=142.55..245.95 rows=133 width=54) (actual time=33.732..68.199 rows=11663 loops=1)                                                                                                                               |
|              ->  HashAggregate  (cost=142.13..143.46 rows=133 width=37) (actual time=33.697..35.988 rows=11872 loops=1)                                                                                                                       |
|                    Group Key: (u0_1.object_pk)::uuid                                                                                                                                                                                          |
|                    Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2209kB                                                                                                                                                                                           |
|                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.55..141.79 rows=133 width=37) (actual time=0.228..26.688 rows=11872 loops=1)                                                                                                                      |
|                          ->  Seq Scan on auth_permission u2  (cost=0.00..6.99 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.181..0.186 rows=1 loops=1)                                                                                                       |
|                                Filter: ((content_type_id = 89) AND ((codename)::text = 'view_texthighlight'::text))                                                                                                                           |
|                                Rows Removed by Filter: 265                                                                                                                                                                                    |
|                          ->  Index Only Scan using guardian_userobjectpermi_user_id_permission_id_ob_b0b3d2fc_uniq on guardian_userobjectpermission u0_1  (cost=0.55..114.05 rows=2075 width=41) (actual time=0.038..7.742 rows=11872 loops=1)|
|                                Index Cond: ((user_id = 1522) AND (permission_id = u2.id))                                                                                                                                                     |
|                                Heap Fetches: 0                                                                                                                                                                                                |
|              ->  Index Scan using annotation_texthighlight_pkey on annotation_texthighlight  (cost=0.42..0.77 rows=1 width=54) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=11872)                                                                  |
|                    Index Cond: (uuid = (u0_1.object_pk)::uuid)                                                                                                                                                                                |
|        ->  Index Scan using annotation_annotation_pkey on annotation_annotation u0  (cost=0.42..0.53 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=11663)                                                                           |
|              Index Cond: (uuid = annotation_texthighlight.annotation_id)                                                                                                                                                                      |
|              Filter: ((min_revision_id = ANY ('{5a301886-e200-441b-ad8e-03c4eb9bd773,6f539d6f-c9eb-41f2-956e-32b4a5950c33}'::uuid[])) AND (chapter_id = '9a481c82-c44b-4ecd-94bb-48de0910877b'::uuid))                                        |
|              Rows Removed by Filter: 1                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
|  ->  Index Scan using annotation_annotation_pkey on annotation_annotation  (cost=0.42..0.52 rows=1 width=125) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=1561)                                                                                    |
|        Index Cond: (uuid = annotation_texthighlight.annotation_id)                                                                                                                                                                            |
|Planning Time: 4.189 ms                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
|Execution Time: 98.961 ms                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Postgres on Heroku

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=7.33..978.55 rows=1 width=180) (actual time=9.721..63411.623 rows=1561 loops=1)                                                                                                                   |
|  Join Filter: (annotation_texthighlight.uuid = (u0_1.object_pk)::uuid)                                                                                                                                                        |
|  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 46967551                                                                                                                                                                                        |
|  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=7.24..13.28 rows=1 width=180) (actual time=0.415..139.459 rows=4745 loops=1)                                                                                                                          |
|        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=7.16..13.17 rows=1 width=142) (actual time=0.406..89.086 rows=4745 loops=1)                                                                                                                     |
|              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on annotation_annotation u0  (cost=7.07..9.08 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.394..11.477 rows=4745 loops=1)                                                                                |
|                    Recheck Cond: ((chapter_id = '9a481c82-c44b-4ecd-94bb-48de0910877b'::uuid) AND (min_revision_id = ANY ('{5a301886-e200-441b-ad8e-03c4eb9bd773,6f539d6f-c9eb-41f2-956e-32b4a5950c33}'::uuid[])))            |
|                    Heap Blocks: exact=163                                                                                                                                                                                     |
|                    ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=7.07..7.07 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.373..0.375 rows=0 loops=1)                                                                                                                  |
|                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on annotation_annotation_chapter_id_d4a757a7  (cost=0.00..2.35 rows=174 width=0) (actual time=0.120..0.121 rows=4825 loops=1)                                                  |
|                                Index Cond: (chapter_id = '9a481c82-c44b-4ecd-94bb-48de0910877b'::uuid)                                                                                                                        |
|                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on annotation_annotation_min_revision_id_e84e9c27  (cost=0.00..4.68 rows=339 width=0) (actual time=0.246..0.246 rows=4825 loops=1)                                             |
|                                Index Cond: (min_revision_id = ANY ('{5a301886-e200-441b-ad8e-03c4eb9bd773,6f539d6f-c9eb-41f2-956e-32b4a5950c33}'::uuid[]))                                                                    |
|              ->  Index Scan using annotation_annotation_pkey on annotation_annotation  (cost=0.08..4.09 rows=1 width=126) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=4745)                                                        |
|                    Index Cond: (uuid = u0.uuid)                                                                                                                                                                               |
|        ->  Index Scan using annotation_texthighlight_annotation_id_key on annotation_texthighlight  (cost=0.08..0.12 rows=1 width=54) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=4745)                                            |
|              Index Cond: (annotation_id = annotation_annotation.uuid)                                                                                                                                                         |
|  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.09..964.62 rows=142 width=37) (actual time=0.042..7.175 rows=9899 loops=4745)                                                                                                                       |
|        ->  Seq Scan on auth_permission u2  (cost=0.00..4.00 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.028..0.032 rows=1 loops=4745)                                                                                                      |
|              Filter: ((content_type_id = 89) AND ((codename)::text = 'view_texthighlight'::text))                                                                                                                             |
|              Rows Removed by Filter: 254                                                                                                                                                                                      |
|        ->  Index Only Scan using guardian_userobjectpermi_user_id_permission_id_ob_b0b3d2fc_uniq on guardian_userobjectpermission u0_1  (cost=0.09..953.57 rows=2353 width=41) (actual time=0.013..6.360 rows=9899 loops=4745)|
|              Index Cond: ((user_id = 1522) AND (permission_id = u2.id))                                                                                                                                                       |
|              Heap Fetches: 46834604                                                                                                                                                                                           |
|Planning Time: 0.733 ms                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
|Execution Time: 63412.909 ms                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The difference seems to be that locally Postgres is using `HashAggregate  (cost=142.13..143.46 rows=133 width=37) (actual time=33.697..35.988 rows=11872 loops=1)` while on Heroku its doing a `Bitmap Heap Scan on annotation_annotation`.

Comment: Try to remove the CAST from your query and rerun it.  If that fixes your performance issue ( which it did for our guardian issue ) I can instruct you how to fix it in your app ( but it requires implementing guardians direct foreign key tables then forking the library to fix a performance issue in the library itself ).  I am 90% sure that's your issue and I've been meaning to issue this as a PR against the Guardian library.  As an aside, we are using guardian for an app that has about 400,000,000 group object permissions.  Once we started hitting the 100m we started having to fork and fix